# Проблемы с кодировкой ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Создал таблицу в БД, но при добавлении символов кириллицы, символ '?', знаю что это проблемы с кодировкой, но как установить UTF-8 в БД?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static void Add_User(string login, string password, string firstName, string secondName, string secretQuestion, string responseQuestion, DateTime birthDay)
{
    string sqlExpression = "INSERT INTO Users (Login, Password, FirstName, SecondName, Birthday, SecretQuestion, ResponseQuestion) " +
        string.Format("VALUES (" + @"'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, '{5}', '{6}'" + ")", login, password, firstName, secondName, birthDay.ToString("u").Replace(" 00:00:00Z", ""), secretQuestion, responseQuestion);
    SqlCommand comAdd = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, _dbConnection);
    comAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: что возвращает SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186939.aspx

Comment: укажите типы колонок FirstName и т.п.

Comment: А как устанавливается соединение с БД?
Не пробовали указать `CharSet=utf8` в connection string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вам нужен именно Unicode, то встроенной поддержки для хранения Unicode-ных строк в кодировке UTF-8 в SqlServer нет, поддерживается только кодировка UTF-16.

Для хранения Unicode-ных строк существуют типы данных `nchar` и `nvarchar`. Соответственно нужные столбцы в таблице должны иметь соответствующий тип. Например:

```
create table Users
(
    FirstName nvarchar(20),
    LastName nvarchar(30)
);
```

Если с типами всё в порядке, но, к примеру, такая

```
insert into Users (FirstName, LastName)
values ('Имя', 'Фамилия');
```

вставка создаёт запись с `???`, то скорее всего collation базы данных отличается от кириллического (проверить collation заданный для БД можно выполнив скрипт `select collation_name from sys.databases where database_id = db_id()`).
В этом случае перед строковым литералом, содержащим нелатинские символы, добавьте `N`, чтобы SqlServer воспринимал его как Unicode. Т.е., например, `N'Имя'` вместо `'Имя'`:

```
insert into Users (FirstName, LastName)
values (N'Имя', N'Фамилия');
```

Вообще для `nvarchar` литералов с нелатинскими символами я бы посоветовал добавлять `N` всегда, чтобы не зависеть от collation базы.

Что касается кода вашего метода `Add_User`, то он уязвим для sql-injection атаки. Вместо формирования строки с литералами безопаснее использовать *параметризованный запрос*.

Answer (score 2):

В SQL Server нет поддержки UTF-8, но есть UTF-16. Подробнее [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/qingsongyao/sql-server-and-utf-8-encoding-1-true-or-false).

Установить кодировку в базе данных можно так.

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

или для cyrillic

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
```

Проверить кодировку в базе данных можно так

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

См. MSDN "[Поддержка параметров сортировки и Юникода](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)"

Comment: вижу очередной минус от "экспертов". где ваши правильные ответы? :)

Comment: Минус не мой, если что :)))