# Знаки вопросов вместо кириллицы в таблице БД при сохранения из textbox asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Записываю в textbox запись на русском, а в таблице отображаются знаки вопроса. Все перерыл ответа так и не нашел.

Comment: БД MS SQL Server?

Comment: совершенно верно

Comment: если поле типа char или varсhar - проверяйте настройки локали сервера. Или используйте nchar и nvarchar, они полностью соответствуют строкам C#, т.е. используют юникод

Comment: используется тип nvarchar

Comment: а чем просматриваете содержимое?

Comment: просматриваю через grid view

Comment: @АнтонТкалич через собаку можно обращаться адресно, чтобы тот к кому вы обращаетесь получал уведомления. Раз там уже юникод, тогда где-то на вашей стороне не правильно распознается кодировка. Но это уже без кода не скажешь

Comment: автор вопроса или ответа получает уведомления автоматически. Еще вариант, что не правильно задана кодировка страницы и браузер отображает не верно. Попробуйте в ручную поменять кодировку страницы при просмотре, если поможет, ищите где забыли указать кодировку страницы

Comment: @rdorn      string InsertQuery = "";
            InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Form (Name, Email) VALUES ('" + Name.Text + "','" + Email.Text + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
            SqlCommand idlast = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, Connection);
            string last = idlast.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Comment: @rdorn кодировку на utf-8 имеете в виду? если да то везде менял ничего не происходит

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome-ru/UUg3G3qcCS4/ylWG_Q_BCwAJ вот вам еще, если из хрома смотрите

Comment: А в БД данные нормально сохранились, или `???`? Если в БД вместо данных вопросы, то посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483640/193999).