# Почему string с кириллицей неправильно отображется в mssql?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Проблема такая: загоняю

```
MySqlConnection.InsertIntoOrders("Вероника Л.", "89991509999", "1788", "2018-04-01 12:01:00", 2, "2018-04-01 12:10:00");
```

где MySqlConnection стат класс в другой сборке.

Это логика в этом InsertIntoOrders:

```
Decimal pay1 = Decimal.Parse(pay);
string formatDec = "{0:0.00}";
DateTime crDate1 = DateTime.Parse(crDate);
DateTime lastModi1 = DateTime.Parse(lastModi);
string format = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".ToLower();
myCommand = new SqlCommand();

myCommand.CommandText = string.Format(
    "Insert Into Orders (name_client, phone_client, pay_client,create_date_order,id_status,last_modif_order)"
    + "Values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", name, phone, pay1, crDate1.ToString(format),
    status, lastModi1.ToString(format));
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
int number = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Добавлено" + number);
```

А на выходе получаю, что в таблице name_client - ???????? ?. В MSSQL стоит nvarchar и кириллица там нормально работает для остальных строк, которые я вводил без кода, т.е. в самой SSMS. Как сделать, чтобы кириллица норм заносилась и не было кракозябров?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с кодировкой ADO.NET](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483640/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-ado-net)

Comment: `MySqlConnection` - это ваш собственный класс? Он никак не связан с СУБД MySQL? Если так, то дайте ему другое название, не вводящее в заблуждение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не склеивайте SQL через String.Format, используйте параметры:

```
myCommand.CommandText = string.Format(
            "Insert Into Orders (name_client, phone_client, ..., last_modif_order)"
            + "Values (@name, @phone, ..., @lastModi1)"; // без кавычек
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
// ...
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastModi1", lastModi1); // как DateTime, без .ToString
```

Иначе получите полный набор проблем, от SQL Injection до неверной кодировки строк и форматирования дат.

а еще лучше - [используйте Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

---

А так - вы строки вставляете как varchar (`'строка'`. Константы типа nvarchar записываются как `N'строка'`).

Comment: Понял, буду имеенить в виду, а можно конкретнее про ошибки кодировки?

Comment: @NickNick это то, что в вашем случае происходит - вы отдаете unicode строку, ее перегоняет в не-unicode в collation базы, и обратно в unicode (nvarchar)

Comment: @NickNick вобщем, используйте параметры. за слеивание SQL обычно сразу расстреливают :)